# Generate enum from deeply nested xsd elements

Tags: java, enums, xsd, jaxb

I'm having a problem generating enum from deeply nested xsd elements. When I generate the code during maven build, my enums are of type string. Here's an example.

```
 <xs:element name="Car">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name="CarModal">
        <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="Type">
               <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                     <xs:enumeration value="SomeValue"/>
                     <xs:enumeration value="AnotherValue"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
               </xs:simpleType>
             </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
        </xs:completType>
     </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
```

From the above example we would have another 20 elements inside of Car element that contains enum value name 'Type'. I have a binding file to bind 'Type' to jaxb:typesafeEnumClass but it's not working, i'm still getting strings as my enum type. Here's an example of my binding.

```
<jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="someLocation">
   <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Car']>
      <jaxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='CarModal']">
         <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='Type']/xs:simpleType>
            <jaxb:typesafeEnumClass name="Type"/>
         </jaxb:bindings>
      </jaxb:bindings>
   </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Thanks for any help and I can't change the xsd

Answer (score 1):

I guess your bindings are nor precise enough. When you write `//xs:element[@name='CarModal']`, you basically say "any `CarModal` element inside my schema". Next, you say you have many `Type` elements so `xs:element[@name='Type']/xs:simpleType` is not precise enough.

Try more precise expressions like

```
xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='CarModal']/
xs:complexType/xs:sequence/xs:element[@name='Type']/xs:simpleType
```

Next, your binding makes a general impression of the incorrect syntax. For instance this:

```
<jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='Type']/xs:simpleType>
```

is invalid XML (missing `"` after `xs:simpleType`). So it might be the case that you binding is not considered at all - otherwise you should have gotten an error instead of generated code. Double-check if the binding is applied at all.